# Laravel Blade Template : combine string with variable from controller for @yield parameter

Tags: php, templates, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My statement

```
@section('description', 'mastram masti mein aag lage {{ $mast->basti }} mein')
```

results in

```
 mastram masti mein aag lage &lt;?php echo e($mast-&gt;basti); ?&gt; mein
```

Comment: I think `'mastram masti mein aag lage '.$mast->basti.' mein'` (normal PHP concatenation) should work

Comment: I have tried that it treats it as a string.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do the concatenation of the variable here.

So you should do this

```
@section('description', 'mastram masti mein aag lage ' . $mast->basti . ' mein')
```

instead of

```
@section('description', 'mastram masti mein aag lage {{ $mast->basti }} mein')
```

Comment: It didn't work. I am using laravel 5.6.x version. Laravel executing $mast->basti as string.

Comment: @section('description', 'mastram masti mein aag lage {!!  $mast->basti !!} mein') try this

Comment: I tried but, didn't work. Also tried    @section('description', 'mastram masti mein aag lage {{!! $mast->basti !!}} mein')